# Piping password to smbpasswd

Tags: automation, installation, debian, samba

How can I pipe the new password to smbpasswd so I can automate my installation process.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Thanks to Mark I found the answer:

```
(echo newpassword; echo confirmNewPassword) | smbpasswd -s
```

BTW: (echo oldpasswd; echo newpasswd) | smbpasswd -s  does not work.

Comment: -1 This is exactly the answer of Mark, just changing variable names.

Comment: +1 to offset JorgeeFG; I think that the new variable names contain a distinction, if you read closely. Mark's answer implies that smbpasswd is expecting an old password and a new one, but this answer implies that smbpasswd is expecting a password and a password confirmation. The second interpretation is the correct one, and so I feel Mark's answer is less helpful than this one.

Answer (score 28):

I use the following in one of my scripts:

```
   echo -ne "$PASS\n$PASS\n" | smbpasswd -a -s $LOGIN
```

With echo:

-e : escape sequences, like \n

-n : don't add implicit newline at end

With smbpasswd:

-a : add new user

-s : silent

Comment: or `echo -ne "$PASS\n" | tee - | smbpasswd -a -s $LOGIN`?

Comment: smbpasswd’s -s stands for “use stdin for password prompt”, not “silent”

Comment: @Michael according to https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/smbpasswd.8.html it means both "silent" (no prompts) and "read from stdin" (instead of /dev/ptty)

Answer (score 13):

Try something like this:

```
(echo oldpasswd; echo newpasswd) | smbpasswd -s
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this
`echo 'somepassword' | tee - | smbpasswd -s`

Comment: thanks, fwiw that's the only syntax I could get working in a Dockerfile: 

`RUN PASS=myrootpassword ; echo ${PASS} | tee - | smbpasswd -a -s`

Comment: I also found this answer useful as the only syntax I could get working in a Puppet exec resource; the approach beginning with a paren failed because Puppet couldn't find the command "(echo". Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had to create a new Samba user in a Puppet 5.x Exec resource and for various reasons none of the above worked. Fortunately this rather silly-looking command worked:

```
yes vagrant|head -n 2|smbpasswd -a -s vagrant
```

Password here is of course "vagrant".

Answer (score 1):

This unfortunately is not desirable for two reasons:
1) if the user uses a combination of '\n' in the password there will be a mismatch in the input
2) if there are unix users on the system, then a user using the utility ps may see the password

A better way would be to put the names in a file and read from the file and use python pexpect to read them, not like below, but the simple script is enough to see how to use pexpect

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#converted from: http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html
#child = pexpect.spawn('scp foo myname@host.example.com:.')
#child.expect ('Password:')
#child.sendline (mypassword)
import pexpect
import sys
user=sys.argv[1]
passwd=sys.argv[2]
child = pexpect.spawn('/usr/bin/smbpasswd -a '+str(user))
child.expect('New SMB password:')
child.sendline (passwd)
child.expect ('Retype new SMB password:')
child.sendline (passwd)
```

then try: ./smbpasswd.py userName1 'f#@(&*(_\n895'

Answer (score -4):

using either [pipelines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) or [redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(Unix)).

Comment: This simply doesn't answer the question.