# Change user password in samba server with the pdbedit tool

Tags: bash, samba, change-password

I am trying to change user password with script but I'm having trouble using the -t option. Here's what I try:

```
echo -e "12345\n12345\n" | pdbedit -t -u username
```

So this is wrong somehow. Any ideas what I am missing or what should I try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ printf "%s\n%s\n" pwd pwd|pdbedit -t -r -u user
```

does not appear to work either

According to http://git.samba.org/?p=samba.git;a=blob;f=source3/utils/pdbedit.c
the `--password-from-stdin` parameter (`pw_from_stdin`) *only affects account creation*.

Thus, you'll rather prefer [smbpasswd](https://superuser.com/questions/99928)

```
$ printf "%s\n%s\n" pwd pwd|smbpasswd -s user
```

( [Piping password to smbpasswd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009/piping-password-to-smbpasswd) )

Comment: In regards to the `-r` option of `pdbedit`: This flag is kept for backwards compatibility, but it is no longer necessary to specify it.