# Communicating with smbpasswd with Python subprocesses using stdin/stdout

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I've been trying to communicate with a program (smbpasswd) using Python's subprocess module without much success. I can communicate with a different program, (e.g. grep) without any trouble, so the problem is specific to smbpasswd. To illustrate the problem, the following code works:

```python
>>> p = Popen(["grep", "n"], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
>>> stdout = p.communicate(input='one\ntwo\n')[0]
>>> print(stdout)
one
```

However, the following does not:

```
>>> p = Popen(["smbpasswd", "-r", server, "-U", user], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
>>> stdout = p.communicate(input='old_password')[0]
>>> print(stdout)
```

The difference is that grep waits for user input after calling the initial "grep f", while smbpasswd prompts the user to input their old password ("Old SMB password:" is displayed if you run the command in a terminal) before looking for input.

This is, however, where my knowledge ends. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009/piping-password-to-smbpasswd

Comment: Utilities that work with passwords typically do not use `stdin`, they open a direct connection to a terminal for security reasons.  Take a look at expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect) to achieve what I want. I am pretty sure smbpassword opens like `su -c` a `PTY` and you can't use subprocess to communicate through a `PTY`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell `smbpasswd` to use stdin for the password prompt.  From the help text:

```
When run by root:
    smbpasswd [options] [username]
otherwise:
    smbpasswd [options]

options:
  -s                   use stdin for password prompt
```

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but I'll give it a go at work tomorrow. Thanks!